# Replacing a water pressure regulator valve that's not screwed in

Tags: water, water-pressure, valve

My pressure regulator valve (PRV) is bad and I need to replace it.  After removing the insulation around it, it looks like the union fittings aren't actually screwed into the PRV.  It doesn't leak or anything, but I'm just really not sure how this is held in.

[image: Pressure regulating valve]

I've tried to remove this via the nuts on each side, but they're on very tight.  I'm beginning to think that these are glued in and my only way forward would be to cut the PVC and reinstall with some other union fittings that connect the PVC to brass.

Does this sound like the proper way forward or does anyone else have any advice for me?

Thanks!

Comment: one union fitting

Comment: have you opened the regulator?

Comment: I haven't tried opening the regulator.  Is there something specific I should look at inside of it?

Comment: no idea ... you said it is defective ... it opens ... you can't make it worse ... maybe it just needs to be cleaned

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That regulator is both internally and externally threaded so it can be connected to multiple sizes of pipes.

I think the best way forward is to cut the CPVC after the regulator, and install the union at the cut.

Comment: Looks like close nipples have been threaded into the internal threads using teflon tape ( white).  Maybe just a bigger wrench, the worst that can happen is that you will need to cut the cpvc.

Comment: Thanks! I tried some bigger wrenches and could get it to move, but loosening one side ended up tightening the other. I couldn’t move anything independently. I ended up cutting one cpvc side and unscrewing the other side. After this replacing it was easy.